# How do I get rid of small kinks on path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, pen-tool

I am trying to draw a snake on Illustrator and I want it to have smooth and rounded edges, but I am struggling to achieve that perfectly with the pen tool.

I have included a close up to illustrate what I'm talking about. The pen tool is a little hard to get the hang of when you need a precise shape or so it seems.[image]

I know I can use the free hand pencil tool but I want to learn to use the pen tool,

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Click and drag when you begin a path, and also when you close the path. This will make the join a smooth anchor rather than a corner anchor.

Example

[image: Example]

Alternatively, if you've already accidentally made a corner anchor, select the anchor with the Direct Selection Tool <kbd>A</kbd>, and change the anchor to a smooth anchor by clicking on the "Convert selected anchor points to smooth" button in the tool options along the top.

Example

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!!! I will familiarize myself with this now.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with the `Smooth Tool` which does precisely that, it smooths out rough corners in a path. Double click the tool icon to reach the settings, where you can adjust how accurate you need it to be.

There is also something called `Simplify Path` which could possibly help if you have many of these 'kinks'.

A lot of Youtube videos about these, so do some research.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip and encouragement! I will look some tutorials up now that you both have helped me with some of the terminology!